# I am educated in?

Tags: riddle

I go with a lady and she called me a snake

I go with grandma, and she turned me into a shake

What am I?

Explain the title also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be

> **BA** and so a Bachelor of Arts for the title.

With a lady

> **mamba** - a genus of venomous snakes from Africa, mam is the mother today.

With grandmother

> **banana** - a type of milkshake, nana being a grandma.

Comment: Fantastic @Tom.

Comment: @RogerA -  very suitable for [today in UK/Ireland](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Day) :)

Comment: Nice work. And what does the question title mean?

Comment: @justhalf the first spoiler block.